# Ajax call for simple form insertion doesn't appear on my system on the actual Web Server?

Tags: php, ajax, linux, amazon-web-services, web

my main.js

```
function codershow(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"ajax.php?flag=codershow",
    type:"post",
    success:function(result){
      $(".sidenavs").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

the ajax file has switch caller for the flag

```
case "codershow":
  $forms->codershow();
  break;
```

Forms php file

```
public function codershow(){

        echo "<form onsubmit='admincode();return false;'>
                <div class='input-group'>
                  <div class='input-group-prepend'>
                    <span class='input-group-text' id='basic-addon1'><img src='imgs/logos/code.png' style='width:20px;'></span>
                  </div>
                  <input id='scode' type='password' class='form-control' placeholder='ADMIN CODE' aria-label='Username' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'>
                </div>
                <button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' style='cursor:pointer;float:right;margin-right:115px;'>PASS</button>
              </form>";
      }
```

Comment: how is the ajax function called? Are there errors in the PHP error log relating to this on live server? Do any calls to `ajax.php` succeed on live server?

Comment: The ajax function is called via onclick process from an A tag, and the javascript will call the ajax.php. Sorry for the messy question, I am still new to web development and I am also assigned to put it into the web server. The system works fine on the local host but in the web server the javascript effects for the picture works and other slideshow images but the ajax call has the problem. I am so glad there is someone who replied on this. I am already thanking you Sir so much

Comment: Use the `console` in the browser to inspect the network request - looks for errors & report

Comment: It states Post:myurl jquery line where xhr.send((options.hascontent&&options.data)||null);

Comment: Http error 500 is the main error sir

Comment: Got it sir, the error is rooted by the constructors of my database, i still haven t configured my db yet